# How to make rails root change daily?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, controller, routes

I am building a scheduling platform for a client. One requirement is that the root be the show page for **today's** schedule. The schedules for other days all need their own show pages, too.

I know how to write a query that will find today's schedule, but I'm having a hard time figuring out how to connect that with my routes file.

Here's what I have so far--right now I'm trying to just get it to render the show page with today's schedule. I could build a custom view for this, but I'm trying to not repeat myself, and it really would be **exactly** the same view as a regular show.

In the schedules controller:

```
def show
    @schedule = Schedule.find(params[:id]) #this is actually done in a :set_schedule before_action callback, but I'm show it it here for clarity.
  end

  def today
    @schedule = Schedule.find_by_date("#{Time.now.year}-#{Time.now.month}-#{Time.now.day}")
    if @schedule 
      render 'schedules/show' #How do I tell it to render the show page for @schedule here??
    else
      render 'welcome#index'
    end
  end
```

When I try to hit myapp.com/schedules/today that throws an error (there is no schedule with id = today).

I imagine that once I get this working, I can just do this in my routes.rb:

```
root 'schedules#today'
```

I want to know--is this the right approach? If so, can you offer some help on my custom controller action? If not, how would you do it?

Comment: You want `render "schedules/show"` to get it to render the show view in schedules.

Comment: How do I tell it to render the schedule that the query finds, though? I'm still getting an error because it's trying to find a schedule with id = today.

Comment: It will render the show view.  The show view appears to use `@schedule` as you've defined it within the today action it will use that schedule.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd bet that you have a `resource :schedules` entry in your routes file that will be intercepting the `schedules/today` and treating `today` as an ID for the show action.

You need to add the collection method `today` to that resource route definition.

```
resources :schedules do 
  collection do
    get :today
  end
end
```

Something along those lines should get you there!

Comment: That worked! Thank you. I had get :today in my routes.rb file, but not inside that collection block.